# DB2 ADO.NET connectors only installs 32-bit connectors

Tags: db2, ado.net, db2-luw

I am running the latest DB2 connectors installer at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/download-initial-version-115-clients-and-drivers and downloading & installing "IBM Data Server Driver Package (DS Driver)"

It installs the 32-bit ADO.NET connectors and puts them in the 32-bit machine.config.

But it puts no entries in the 64-bit machine.config (I have 64-bit Windows 10).

How can I get the 64-bit connectors installed?

Comment: have you paid attention that there are both options to download ?  32 and 64bit for windows ? `(Windows 32-bit AMD and Intel x86)` and `(Windows 64-bit AMD64 and Intel EM64T)` options ?

Comment: @SamuelPizarro Yes. And I downloaded the 64-bit Windows version.

Comment: @SamuelPizarro One of my rules is no matter how sure I am of something, if someone says check X, then check it again. You were right. I blew it and must have installed the 32-bit version. If you make that an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you have selected the correct driver.
There are different download options for 32 and/or 64bit on that page.

And if that is the case,  no worries..   who never did something like that!

Comment: I love your second para :)